The classes.dex in my Android APK is very large. How can I make it smaller?
I have developed a simple app using Jetpack Compose, but I've noticed that the APK size is quite large at around 21 MB. When I analyzed the APK, I found that classes.dex is contributing significantly to the size, weighing in at about 16 MB.
Could you provide some guidance on how to reduce the APK size and optimize the classes.dex file? Specifically, I am interested in strategies for minimizing the app's footprint while maintaining its functionality.
enter image description here
i try change build.gralde isMinifyEnabled to true.but it didn't make much of a difference

Most likely a large part is caused by Kotlin. Kotlin has it's own standard library that extends the standard Java runtime. Those classes have to be included into your app. And Jetpack Compose add additional classes. BTW: You have to sum the size of all classes*.dex files (therefore your classes dex files have a size of 21MB). They are only split up to multiple files because if internal size restrictions of dex files. If you want to see what classes are in each dex file use https://apktool.org to decompile your apk. It will create for each dex file an own smali folder.

what are the third party libraries do you using,
for my case, i added a poi xml (5mb) that increase my app size to 17 + 5 mb
you can share your build.gradle dependecy file, it'll be useful
(and hide your api keys before sharing it)
